# Loop through and update MySQL after specific row in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a game that allows players to store items in a MySQL database. I've got a table that stores every player's items. It's slot based, with each item having a unique value.
So the table would have something like:
id, itemvalue, slot, playerID.

I'm trying to figure out a way in PHP to allow the player to withdraw or deposit an item in a specific slot.

I need help updating entries after an action (withdraw or deposit) has taken place.
For example:
Say a player can have 10 slots for themselves.
If the player withdraws an item from slot 4, how do I loop through their items from slots 5 to 10 and update the values to be -1 for their slot.

Of course, I'm getting the information from the table, let's call it "ItemTable" by using:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ItemTable WHERE playerID ='$_playerID' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Hum.. Are you sure that you really need the 'id' ? You could use as primary key in your table the pair (playerID,slotNumber) and so your problem would be VERY simpler ( something like 'UPDATE ITEMTABLE SET itemvalue=-1 WHERE playerID = ... and slotNum > 4)

Comment: I'll look into more modern ways of using PHP and MySQL. I've only started a few months, so I will find it no problem learning a new API.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
UPDATE ItemTable SET slot=slot-1 WHERE playerID='$_playerID' AND slot>$withdrawnItemSlot
```

That should shuffle all the other items up a slot.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's the one that I went with and worked. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Would be something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM ItemTable WHERE id > (SELECT itemID FROM ItemTable WHERE playerID='$_playerID') t2 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10"
```

I mean to update, you do that:

```
"UPDATE ItemTable WHERE id > (SELECT itemID FROM ItemTable WHERE playerID='$_playerID') t2 SET (here you go with your updates) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10"
```

(not sure if select should be named in this case, if it won't work, just remove "t2" from above queries)